# Alerts are displayed in Chrome and Explorer, but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that works correctly and displays the alerts in Chrome and Explorer but not in Firefox. However, the function do his works correctly in Firefox, but the alerts are not displayed or displayed very fast and I can't click the "Ok" button of then. Any help I receive I'll be gratefull. Sorry for mi english, it's not my native language. Here is the code. The alerts are "ALERT ONE" and "ALERT TWO".
'

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: direccion,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: post,
            success: function(data) {
                document.location = direccion;
                if(data.valid == 0) {
                    alert('ALERT ONE');
                } else if(data.valid == 1) {
                    alert('ALERT TWO');
                } else {

                }
                document.location = "autenticacion.php";
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you checked the 'do not allow this site to show more alerts' checkbox in FF?

Answer (score 5):

With this line at the start of your callback

```
document.location = direccion;
```

no browser should display any alert as the page should change immediately.

Comment: @Victor yes, please explain why you are doing this

Comment: But in Chrome and Explorer the alerts are shown normally =( The problem is only in Firefox

Comment: The problem is your code ... after redirecting with `document.location` no browser will reliably continue with any code on the current page

Comment: The is a form. I validate login in autenticacion.php. If the user doesn't have some  permissions, ALERT ONE is displayed. If the user doesn't have some other permissions, ALERT TWO is displayed. That's why i go to the autenticacion.php page again.

Comment: But why are you changing the document.location the first time before the tests ?

Comment: But the alerts are before of the document.location. How could emulate that behavior in other way?

Comment: No, you change the location twice : just before and just after. The first time seems erroneous.

Comment: You have TWO redirections with `document.location`. Look at your code. The first one is before(!) the alerts.

Comment: direccion = "autenticar.php";
in that file i check the permissions of the user.

Comment: That's the content of "direccion" i mean

Comment: Yes ... and WHY are you redirecting to it after you already requested the authenticar.php using $.ajax() ?

Comment: In the first document.location i go to "autenticar.php"
In the second document.location i go back to "autenticacion.php".

Comment: Let me think that for a second, i'm newbie in this

Comment: $.ajax() will already request autenticar.php, no need to redirect to it after this request finished.

Comment: @Víctor yes, take the time you need to read carefully the comments and the code sample.

Comment: You say that it's not correct the second document.location inside the $.ajax?

Comment: I do that because in that point, i want to go back to autenticacion.php

Comment: The first one is the main problem : any `document.location=something;` ends the script as it asks for the page to change.

Comment: autenticar.php is a fila and autenticacion.php is other

Comment: But when the process in autenticar.php ends, it return to that point, right?

Comment: No. The script has ended, this is a whole new page. Retry without the line I pointed. Then try to understand all what happens.

Comment: Please try to understand that $.ajax() has already finished requesting autenticar.php and afterwards your code tries to redirect to autenticar.php, so actually your code is requesting autenticar.php twice. Please remove the `document.location = direccion` line in your code and test it

Comment: I'll test it now. I remove that line. I understand what you told me. =) But the behavior is still the same =(

Comment: Yes! That was the problem! I clean the history of the brower and test it again and now it works! Than you very much. I'm really really thakfull. Really! Hugs, thanks again! =)

Comment: Than you very much @devnull69 i'm really thankful! The problem was that, the call to autenticar.php twice =)

Comment: Than you very much @dystroy i'm really thankful! The problem was that, the call to autenticar.php twice =)